# Managing different accounts in stack overflow

Tags: discussion, support

I have an account in Stack overflow and as well in cross validated with different user id.

Is it possible to link the two accounts from different user ID?

If yes , then how to link both the accounts so that I can view all my accounts on the same profile as like below pic:

[image]

Comment: when you say different `user id` did you `(1):` Make a StackExchange account or `(2):`use Google, Facebook etc to sign in ?

Comment: I mean different sign-in as well different gmail account . I will sign in stack overflow account using gmail account and cross validated account using Facebook sign.Both account has different mail id(not the same account)

Comment: So add the first accounts gmail id into the second accounts login like I described. The system should then link your accounts.

Comment: I tried of...but it prompt 'page not found' error msg...

"Page Not Found
We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.

Try searching for similar questions
Browse recent questions
Browse popular tags
If you feel something is missing that should be here, contact us".

what should I do now!!

Comment: When does it give you a `Page not found` ? Can you describe the steps before the error?

Comment: Now its working ... thx :)

Comment: Looks like your page not found must have just been a small internet issue.  Glad it's working now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update : I didn't realize that the stackoverflow help center has : [*I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

---

**(Read full answer before proceeding)**.

Here is one way I can think of, you have `account A` and `account B`.

**(1)** *Pick/Choose/Think of* one of the login service that SE supports : Google, Facebook, Yahoo, OpenID..etc

**(2)** : Goto your profile page on `account A`, choose `my logins` on the top:

[image: Screenie of Profile page]

**(3)** : In the window that pops up choose `add more logins..` Add the login you picked in **(1)**

[image: My Logins window]

**(4)** : Repeat for `account B`

^^ **Henceforth you login with the account you chose in (1)**.